# Solution of a $1$-dimensional optimal control problem via Riccati equation

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control

In general, the problem
$$
    \min_u \int_0^\infty (x^T Q x + u^TRu) \, dt \quad\text{such that}\quad \begin{cases}\dot x(t) = Ax(t)+Bu(t) \\ x(0) = x_0\end{cases}
$$
has an associated (stationary) Riccati equation given by
$$
    0 = Q+A^TS+SA-SBR^{-1}BS, \quad S\text{ constant}
$$
In particular, consider the $1$-dimensional case where $Q=B=1$, $R=\gamma>0$ and $A=\alpha>0$, that is
$$
    \min_u \int_0^\infty (x^2 + \gamma u^2) \, dt \quad\text{such that}\quad \begin{cases}\dot x(t) = \alpha x(t)+u(t) \\ x(0) = 0\end{cases}
$$

The Riccati equation for this problem is
$$
    S^2-2\alpha\gamma S-\gamma = 0 \quad\Rightarrow\quad S = \alpha\gamma\pm\sqrt{\alpha^2\gamma^2+\gamma}
$$
Since $Q$ and $R$ are positive, the optimal solution of the problem is given by
$$
    u(t) = -R^{-1}B^TSx(t) = -\frac{S}{\gamma}x(t) = \Big(-\alpha\mp\underbrace{\sqrt{\alpha^2+1/\gamma}}_{:= k}\Big)x(t)
$$
So
$$
    \dot x(t) = \mp kx(t),\quad
    \int_0^t \frac{dx(s)}{x(s)} = \mp k \int_0^t ds,\quad
    x(t) = x(0)\exp(\mp kt)
$$
and plugging the initial condition $x(0)=0$ we get $x(t)=u(t)\boxed{=0},\forall t$.

However, on my notes, I read that the solution to
$$
    \min_u \int_0^T(x^2 + \gamma u^2) \, dt \quad\text{such that}\quad \begin{cases}\dot x(t) = A x(t)+Bu(t) \\ x(0) = x_0\end{cases}
$$
is
$$
   x(t)=x_0\exp\bigg(\int_0^t A\,dS\bigg)+\int_0^t \exp\bigg(\int_0^{t-s}Adr\bigg)Bu(s)\,ds
$$
and applying it in our case we would have $x(t) = 0+e^{\alpha t}\int_0^t e^{-\alpha s}u(s)\,ds\boxed{\ne0}$, which contradicts the previous result.

Which one is correct?

Comment: How is your last expression not equal to zero, since when you plug in $u(t)=0$ into the integral should also give zero for the second term right?

Comment: Also your notes are considering the finite time LQR problem, while your initial problem is infinite time LQR.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen ah right thanks, anyway you think that computation for the first part is correct?

Comment: Yes. However, it can be noted that the only the positive definite solution for $S$ would be a minimizing solution. Also, for any LTI state space model with $x(0)=0$, the LQR problem should always yield $u(t)=0$.